# Why TabularInline looks different on differen sites. How to control its apperence

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have 2 different registers on my admin panel and on one TabularInline allows multiple choice:
[image]

and on another not:
[image]

Where does the difference come from? How can I control it?

**Update:**

I have a table movies which is connected to the table person via intermediate table. Table Person has name and role (actor, writer, director). What I am trying to do is to allow in admin panel to see and edit both, e.g. Movies should have 3 different panels, where one can add actor, writer and director. Actor should have name and movie to add.
So far I was able to make 3 panels for movies, but they do not allow several choices and show all names, but not only actors in actors panel (see second picture). Also when I save them, they do not get role - actor. Actors allow to choose several movies, but when I save them, admin blocks me saying "Film work person with this Movie already exists."

My models (I only show part for films and actors, writers and director are the same):

```
class FilmWorkPerson(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    movie = models.OneToOneField('FilmWork', models.CASCADE, unique=False)
    person = models.ForeignKey('Person', models.CASCADE, unique=False)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'film_work_person'
        unique_together = (('movie', 'person'),)
        
        

class FilmWork(models.Model):
    # what we have from sql
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    people = models.ManyToManyField('Person', through=FilmWorkPerson)
    
class Person(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(_('ФИО'), max_length=100)
    role = models.CharField(_('роль'), max_length=100)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now =True)
    movie = models.ManyToManyField(FilmWork, through=FilmWorkPerson)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'person'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
class ActorManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(role='actor')


class Actor(Person):
    objects = ActorManager()

    class Meta:
        proxy = True
        verbose_name = _('actor')
        verbose_name_plural = _('actors')
```

my admin.py:

```
class PersonInlineAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Person.movie.through


class ActorInlineFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(ActorInlineFormSet, self).get_queryset().filter(person__role__iexact='actor')
        self._queryset = qs
        return self._queryset
    
class ActorInlineAdmin2(admin.TabularInline):
    model = FilmWork.people.through
    formset = ActorInlineFormSet
    verbose_name = 'actor'
    verbose_name_plural = 'actors'
    
@admin.register(FilmWork)
class FilmworkAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    # отображение полей в списке
    list_display = ('title', 'ratings', 'created_on', 'actors', 'writers', 'director',
                    'film_creation_date', 'age_limit', 'link')
    def actors(self, obj):
        actors = FilmWork.objects.filter(person__role__iexact='actor', title=obj).values_list('person__name', flat=True)
        return ", ".join([a for a in actors])
    def writers(self, obj):
        writers = FilmWork.objects.filter(people__role__iexact='writer', title=obj).values_list('people__name', flat=True)
        return ", ".join([a for a in writers])
    def director(self, obj):
        director = FilmWork.objects.filter(people__role__iexact='director', title=obj).values_list('people__name', flat=True)
        return ", ".join([a for a in director])

    list_filter = ('genre','film_creation_date', 'age_limit', 'link')

    fields = ('title', 'plot', 'ratings', 'film_creation_date', 'age_limit', 'link')

    search_fields = ('title', 'plot', 'id', 'film_creation_date', 'age_limit', 'link')

    inlines = (GenreInlineAdmin, ActorInlineAdmin2, DirectorInlineAdmin2, WriterInlineAdmin2, )
    
    
@admin.register(Actor)
class Actor(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ('name', )

    fields = ('name', )

    search_fields = ('name', 'movie')

    list_filter = ('movie',)

    inlines = (PersonInlineAdmin,)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand your question clearly, but I'm guessing it's because of the different relationship types between the models, `models.ForeignKey` for the `Genre` vs `models.ManyToManyField` for the `Movie`.

If you can provide more details on what you're trying to achieve, I might be able to help.

Comment: Hi, Thank you! I will edit my post for the details.